# Material ui class based components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Where can I find material ui class based components instead of function based components and if I can,t.
Where to write

```
const classes = useClasses();
const theme = useTheme();
```

in my class component?

Answer (score 0):

There are two HoCs for your use-case, i.e. `withStyles` and `withTheme`.

#### Usage:

```
import React from "react"
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const styles = theme => ({
  wrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    // ...
  }
  // ...
})

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    // ...
    return (
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const EnhancedComponent = withStyles(styles)(ClassComponent)
```

Now you can render `EnhancedComponent`.

Comment: appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width']
    }
   
now told me can't read create of undefined

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can pass a function in withStyles to access the theme and can use in the styles.

Comment: You can read more [here](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#using-createstyles-to-defeat-type-widening)

Answer (score 0):

useTheme - Its a hook, which can be used with functional components
You can however use withTheme for class component.

Refer this link : https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/